# How do you search by highway exit number in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to specify a highway exit number?  e.g. "Exit 62, I-84, OR"

This format doesn't work.  Are there others that will?

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps doesn't seem to have a good way to search with a highway exit number.  However, at the appropriate zoom level it does list the highway exits (where available, according to Google) on the map.  Check [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144339) for more information.

If you want to get directions to or from an exit, locate the exit on the map, right-click and select the appropriate option (Directions from here or Directions to here).